# Monitoring files on a shared drive and auto-check in to TFS

Tags: tfs

We need to monitor files in a share drive and check in file changes (new files or additions/deletions to existing files) to Team Foundation Server. Is it possible to map a TFS path to the shared drive and accomplish this ?

Answer (score 1):

First,TFS is able to work with network/shared drivers. You could also create a workspace on the drive and mapped to TFS. You also be able to  get latest and do some modification, then check in files.

So it's the same as monitoring files on a local drive and auto-check in to TFS. The most concern is the "auto-check in" operation, how would this be achieved. For example when you edit a file on the workspace in share drive, when would you check in files, after edit a character or a line, it's hard to judge when you finished the modification.

Actually if you are working on local  workspace, your demand is by designed. When you had been modified externally VS or directly on files, TFS automatically checked them out without you having to do anything. The changes are added as a "pending change" status.
Lately you could check in the projects in the normal way and save the external modifications.

Certainly, you could also use `tf command` or [TFS API](http://singhtechies.com/programatically-checkin-file-to-tfs-using-c/) to control the check-in operation.